# How to link a particularly named static library in Makefile?

Tags: linker, glfw

I recently used Cmake/MinGW to build the glfw3 library from source. After `make install`, in the **lib** folder, I got the following binaries:

1. glfw3.dll
2. glfw3dll.a

Now to link with the static library in makefile, I changed the name of `glfw3dll.a` to `libglfw3dll.a`, so that I could write the linker flag `-lglfw3dll` in the makefile. But this feels like a hack. Is there a way to do it without changing the name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to do it without changing the name?

Yes, pass:

```
-l:glfw3dll.a
```

BTW, this is a fact about the [commandline options of GNU ld](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#Options). It has nothing to do with `make` or makefiles.

Comment: Thanks very much. Worked. :)